# ¿Cómo hacer para que aparezca el nombre de la columna con un select en php?

Tags: php

Si me puede colaborar con un caso, lo que pasa es que estoy realizando  un buscador, me genera la búsqueda sino que necesito que debe vez  que me aparezca el  registro, me aparezca el nombre de la columna  muchas gracias

```
<td style="color: #084099; font-size:20px; ">Buscar Campaña &nbsp; </td>
<td>
  <select class="form-control"  id="campanasb" name="campanasb"   >
    <option value="0">-Seleccione-</option>
    <?php
      $consulta_grupo ="
        SELECT * 
        FROM siryl.campanas
        WHERE estado='Activo'
        ORDER BY nombre  ";

      $buscar_grupo = mysqli_query($link,$consulta_grupo) or die(mysqli_error());
      while ($bus_grupo = mysqli_fetch_array($buscar_grupo)) 
        {
          echo "<option> value='$bus_grupo[id_campanas]'>".
               $bus_grupo['nombre']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
  </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Quieres que te aparezca el mismo nombre de la columna en todas las opciones?

Comment: si que de vez del registro me traiga el nombre de la columna por ejemplo: si la bases de datos se llama computador y en el nombre de la columna que le coloco es  impresora eso es lo  que necesito que me traiga no necesito que traiga los registros que hay dentro de la columna impresora, muchas gracias si me puede colaborar de como lo podria hacer

Comment: Si tu sabes los nombres de las columnas, no necesitas hacer un query, Tu puedes construir el select con el nombre de las columnas que quieres.

Comment: Pero como lo podía hacer ya que  esta conectado en la bases de datos, cuando el usuario lo filtre eliga el nombre de la columna para que le aparezca la información

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Por favor evita escribir todo `[malgusto]EN MAYÚSCULA[/malgusto]`, pues es de muy mal gusto en el lenguaje informático. Si es posible [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/206862/edit) corrigiendo el título. Y de paso explica un poco mejor lo que quieres, porque no se entiende lo que quieres hacer en tu código. ¿Será que quieres un `SELECT` basado en una columna específica que el usuario elegirá en alguna parte? Explica un poco mejor. Gracias.

Comment: Como te explicaba, puedes hacer un select que contenga todas las columnas por las que quieres filtrar.  Luego ese valor lo pasas a PHP para filtrar por ese valor.

Comment: ¡Hola! Haber si entendí bien, tu quieres que el usuario seleccione de una lista, todas las tablas de tu base de datos y que en base a esa información, es decir, en base a esa tabla seleccionada por el usuario, retorne todas las columnas asociadas. ¿Es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: si eso es lo que necesito muchas gracias

Comment: en la línea `echo "<option> value='$bus_grupo[id_campanas]'>".` parece haber un `>` de mas que cierra el `option` antes del `value=`

Comment: Muchas gracias ya corregí esa parte, pero si me  pueden colaborar con la pregunta, ya que estoy desarrollando unas paginas, muchas gracias por su colaboración

Answer (score 0):

si es un sql server, tienes la opcion information_Schema que sería así

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM database.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Sustituyendo database por el nombre de la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

La siguiente consulta MySQL te devolverá todas las columnas, por su nombre, de una tabla:

```
    SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
         FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
         WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='nombre_base_de_datos' 
         AND `TABLE_NAME`='nombre_tabla'
```

En "TABLE_SCHEMA" ingresas el nombre de tu base de datos y en "TABLE_NAME" el nombre de la tabla, de la cual, quieres obtener el titulo de todas sus columnas.

Comment: mira como lo realice pero no me muestra nada, si me pueden colaborar

Comment: SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                                        FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
                                        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'temas'
                                        AND TABLE_NAME = 'campanas'

Comment: si me puede colaborar para que me aparezca los nombres y ademas como puede especificar para que aparezca el cierto nombre de ciertas columnas muchas gracias

Comment: ya lo  realice pero como lo imprimo para que me lo muestre en la lista

Comment: while ($bus_grupo = mysqli_fetch_array($buscar_grupo)) 
                                        {
                                          
                                            echo "<option value='$bus_grupo[id_campanas]'>".$bus_grupo['nombre']."</option>";
                                      
                                          
                                        }